# Connecting another node to a private testnet

Tags: iota-cli

I´ve set up a private testnet following the [one command tangle](https://docs.iota.org/docs/utils/0.1/community/one-command-tangle/overview) tutorial. It works properly (curl checked)

When I try to connect another node to this private Tangle, I get:

```
Dropping connection to neighbor 172.26.110.183:15600 as handshaking was faulty
```

I am using the following command to launch the second node in a docker container:

```
docker run -d -p 14265:14265 --name iri iotaledger/iri:latest --remote true -p 14265 --testnet true --testnet-coordinator coo_addr --auto-tethering true --neighbors tcp://172.26.110.183:15600 --neighboring-socket-port 15600
```

Am I missing any important parameter?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something but in the second node you should put the IP and port of the first node for `--neighbors`. It looks like you are putting the IP of the wrong node.

Comment: Or maybe you have some funky docker configurations you need to look at

Comment: .183 is the first node ip address... I am going to keep studying the docker configuration to see if I can fix the error

Comment: Did you fix by the way?

Comment: Not yet, still working on it...